# can I create a VM with Terraform in OpenStack (or any other IaaS) and use the new VM's ip address afterwards as an input for another resource?

Tags: terraform

I'm doing my first steps with Terraform and I was wondering if I can do something like this:

```
resource "openstack_compute_instance_v2" "terraform-xx" {

...
...

    provisioner "local-exec" {
      command =  "inspec exec test/smoke/default/* -t ssh://root@***HERE-I-WOULD-NEED-THE-VM-IP*** --password passw0rd" 
    }

}
```

Basically, I need to grab the new VM's ip address in a variable and reference that variable in a local-exec provisioner

Answer (score 1):

With EC2 instances at least you would use [`"${self.private_ip}"`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#available-variables) as the resource outputs a `private_ip` attribute that you can reference.

With the [OpenStack Compute instance](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/openstack/r/compute_instance_v2.html) it looks like you want [`"${self.access_ip_v4}"`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/openstack/r/compute_instance_v2.html#access_ip_v4) but I might wrong on that.